# Running an installation routine of a third party programm on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, software-installation, mime-type

Please help me with the following problem:

I try to install a third party program `install.bin` that is from mime type `application/octet-stream`.

Typing `sudo ./install.bin; echo $?` in the terminal - while the file is executable and in the current folder - doesn't have any effect, except the status according to the echo of "127".

On other computers with the same operation system Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-Bit-based it works fine - the installation is executed.

It seems to be that the Systems treat mime types of the same category in a different way.

Does anybody has an idea how to solve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: If you already installed your `instal.bin` on computer A that has Ubuntu 14.04, and can't install it on computer B that has the same OS, then we can't help you without further details on computer B.

Comment: the hardware configuration of the computer:
Intel Core 2 CPU 6400
Gallium 0.4 on NV49
what else is needed?
Software/Updates for the current system status:
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
apt-get install synaptic
apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
Software should be the same on A and B Hardware is different

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `install.bin; echo $?`

Comment: @BobBaumeister exit code 127 means : `command not found`. Are you sure your `./install.bin` is executable and in the current folder ?

Comment: thanks for your hint. I ensured that it is on the right path, so there must be another reason why it is not working

Comment: Any rogue "characters" in the filename that aren't visible? Worth trying to run after renaming? (+ Info on [exit code 127](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1763156/232251), FWIW.)